# Tag not longer presents

Tags: support, tags

A few weeks ago, I suggested a new tag related to 4K. The suggestion had been accepted but right now I don't see the tag anymore.

Is this normal? There is some regulation related to the evolution of the tags?

Comment: What post had that tag?

Comment: @bmike this one: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228423/mac-pro-50-4k-ultra-hd-led-tv-as-monitor-best-graphics-card

Comment: looks like it was merged into retina tag

Comment: I don' t see it among the synonyms of retina. Anyway if you think this is normal, no problem.

Comment: @bmike when was retina-diaplay synonymed to display which seems wrong

Comment: Feel free to start a thread or discussion in the tags chat room if you want to propose a new tag or changes to synonyms, @Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [suggested edit 151881](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/151881) shows that [4k](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4k) was the tag that was suggested to be added, but the [post revisions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/228423/revisions) shows that [retina-display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retina-display) was added. [4k](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4k) was merged with [retina-display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retina-display), but [retina-display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retina-display) is a synonym of [display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display), and as such [/tags/retina-display/synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/retina-display/synonyms) redirects to [/tags/display/synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/display/synonyms) which doesn't show [4k](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4k) as a synonym, because it isn't. The [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) here is that the question shouldn't be able to be tagged with [retina-display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retina-display) and [display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) at the same time, as the former is a synonym of the latter.

Comment: Sorry if I ask but, knowing that not all the times a retina-display corresponds to a 4k resolution. Isn't it better to have an independent tag for 4k to be used for questions like this: [Mac Pro + 50” 4K Ultra HD LED TV as monitor — Best graphics card?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228423/mac-pro-50-4k-ultra-hd-led-tv-as-monitor-best-graphics-card). Here the question is not referring to retina display!

Comment: @Mattia I somewhat agree. I don't think [retina-display]/etc should be a synonym of [display] which would allow [4k] to be a synonym of [retina-display].

Comment: More precisely, I think that in a Apple environment like Ask Different [retina-display] could be a synonym of [display], nowadays more or less all the Apple displays produced are retina. The point is that 4k in most of the cases is not related to Apple displays and to retina-displays. Anyway, I was just wondering why that tag was accepted and than it disappeared.

Comment: @Mattia If display is linked to retina-display - what do you do for external displays or links via HDMI/VGA or just a generic display of a programetc Out of the newest 10 questions tagged display only one might be tagged as retina

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/151924) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/151923) originally have been the edits for [4k](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4k). I've rejected both because the tag description was incorrect and incomplete.